# How to fix ERROR: Python requirements are missing

Tags: python, pip

I’m trying to make an Xcode project that is python using kivy. When I go to build kivy in terminal it says:

```
ERROR: Python requirements are missing

To install: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I tried running pip install -r requirements.txt around five times and it still gives me that error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please share traceback?

Comment: Do you have requirements file?

Comment: Run `ls` to see whether requirements.txt is in the current directory.

Comment: I did the ls command and it says that requirements.txt is in that directory

Comment: If someone wants to see what i was trying to do go to https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-ios.html